# How can i get the pinterest-like layout with tailwind and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

i'm trying to get a pinterest-like layout but i cannot achieve it,

[Here is what i want :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIW8m.jpg)

[and here is what i get :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nC3d.png)

Here is the div of the card :

```js
<div className='border-[1px] border-blanc rounded-[18px] w-[25rem] h-fit justify-between hover:bg-gray-400/5 cursor-pointer '>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and here is the div that map all the card :

```js
<div className='pt-[5rem] w-[90rem] ml-[2rem] grid grid-cols-3 '>
            {datas.map((e) => (
                    
                <Card posterName={e.posterName} posterUsername={e.posterUsername} content={e.content} likes=           {e.likes} dislikes={e.dislikes} commentsCount={e.commentsCount} key={e.id} id={e.id} repostCount={e.repostCount} image={e.image} />
                    
                ))}
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

i tried flex-wrap, i tried grid but it doesn't work, where is my error please ?

Comment: your code snippets don't work at all - you're putting HTML where there should be javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of layout is called Masonry. It is currently [implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout) in firefox under experimental options.
There is also an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-css) for positioning your elements in such a grid.

Comment: yet ... it pinterest has been around for years

Comment: The reason it works in pinterest is because they position their pictures in columns using javascript. Masonry layout has been around for a long time, but no native implementation in browsers still exist.

Comment: so ... why put that as an answer?

Comment: Because I provided a search term that can help the OP find what they are looking for and provided with links that can help them or anyone else that might stumble upon this answer to implement what they need.

Comment: and find that native masonry layout isn't supported by any browser - great answer

Comment: And..? My answer is valid. Masonry layout is not in the css specification yet. BUT there are implementations of it using javascript which I have linked.

Comment: yeah - fair point - still a link only answer is meh - I tried that once - and got slammed by the stackoverflow illuminati for it

Comment: Thanks you very much it works and it's very easy, thanks again !